# How to move a circle again after being idle for 3 seconds?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently creating a program where a circle will move to the left, stay for 3 seconds, and then move to the right of the screen. However, when trying to implement this solution there: [In PyGame, how to move an image every 3 seconds without using the sleep function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109410/in-pygame-how-to-move-an-image-every-3-seconds-without-using-the-sleep-function), it does not work. I would appreciate if somebody can tell me what am I doing.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

currentPosition = [300, 368]

def moveLeft():
    currentPosition[0] -= 1

def moveRight():
    currentPosition[0] += 1


pygame.init()

windowCalibration = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0))

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)



windowCalibration.fill(WHITE)

pygame.display.set_caption("Eye calibration")
pygame.draw.circle(windowCalibration, (0,0,0), currentPosition, 10)
done = False

circleIsIdle = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

time_counter = 0

def stopCircle():
    circleIsIdle = True
    while circleIsIdle:
        time_counter = clock.tick()
        if time_counter > 3000:
            time_counter = 0
            circleIsIdle = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True
    while currentPosition[0] >= 10:
        moveLeft()
        windowCalibration.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.circle(windowCalibration, (0,0,0), currentPosition, 10)
        pygame.display.update()
    stopCircle()

    while currentPosition[0] <= 1350:
        moveRight()
        windowCalibration.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.draw.circle(windowCalibration, (0,0,0), currentPosition, 10)
        pygame.display.update()
    stopCircle()
    done = True
```

Comment: I think you forgot the `+=` in `time_counter = clock.tick()`

Comment: in `while not done` you should use `pygame.display.update()` only once - at the end of loop. This way it should run smoother. But problem is `while circleIsIdle:` which stops `while not done` and it can't check if you press `ESC`. In game you shouldn't use other `while` which takes longer time.

Comment: Thanks @Pygasm. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `while not done` you shouldn't use other `while` which takes longer time. It stops `while not done` and it can't check if you pressed `ESC`, etc.

You should rather use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get current time and use it to control which element move or draw.

I also use `state` to see if I move left or right or I wait before move left or right. This way I can do different things - I can move or not, I can draw or not (ie. if I have button "Pause" I could use `state_pause` to draw or not this button).

This code runs `while not done` all time so you can always exit using `ESC`. You can also move second circle even when first circle is waiting.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)

# --- classes ---

# empty

# --- functions ---

def moveLeft():
    currentPosition[0] -= 1

def moveRight():
    currentPosition[0] += 1
# --- main ---

pygame.init()

windowCalibration = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0))
pygame.display.set_caption("Eye calibration")

currentPosition = [300, 368]
state = 'move_left'
wait_to = 0

done = False
while not done:

    # --- events ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True

    # --- moves ---

    if state == 'move_left':
        if currentPosition[0] >= 10:
            moveLeft()
        else:
            state = 'wait_before_move_right'
            wait_to = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000

    elif state == 'move_right':
        if currentPosition[0] <= 1350:
            moveRight()
        else:
            state = 'wait_before_move_left'
            wait_to = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000

    elif state == 'wait_before_move_right':
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if current_time > wait_to:
            state = 'move_right'

    elif state == 'wait_before_move_left':
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if current_time > wait_to:
            state = 'move_left'

    # --- draws ----

    windowCalibration.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.draw.circle(windowCalibration, BLACK, currentPosition, 10)
    pygame.display.update()

# --- end ---
pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:** this code moves 3 circles at the same time, they wait before they change direction and it doesn't stops other circles, and you can use `ESC` in any moment.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

# --- classes ---

# empty

# --- functions ---

# empty

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

windowCalibration = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0))
pygame.display.set_caption("Eye calibration")

circles = [
    {'pos': [300, 368], 'speed': 1, 'state': 'move_left', 'wait_to': 0, 'color': RED},
    {'pos': [300, 268], 'speed': 10, 'state': 'move_right', 'wait_to': 0, 'color': GREEN},
    {'pos': [300, 168], 'speed': 30, 'state': 'move_right', 'wait_to': 0, 'color': BLUE},
]

done = False
while not done:

    # --- events ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                done = True

    # --- moves ---

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    for circle in circles:
        if circle['state'] == 'move_left':
            if circle['pos'][0] >= 10:
                circle['pos'][0] -= circle['speed']
            else:
                circle['pos'][0] = 10
                circle['state'] = 'wait_before_move_right'
                circle['wait_to'] = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000

        elif circle['state'] == 'move_right':
            if circle['pos'][0] <= 1350:
                circle['pos'][0] += circle['speed']
            else:
                circle['pos'][0] = 1350
                circle['state'] = 'wait_before_move_left'
                circle['wait_to'] = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000

        elif circle['state'] == 'wait_before_move_right':
            if current_time > circle['wait_to']:
                circle['state'] = 'move_right'

        elif circle['state'] == 'wait_before_move_left':
            if current_time > circle['wait_to']:
                circle['state'] = 'move_left'

    # --- draws ----

    windowCalibration.fill(WHITE)

    for circle in circles:
        pygame.draw.circle(windowCalibration, circle['color'], circle['pos'], 10)

    pygame.display.update()

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Big thanks for your detailed code. I want to make the circle move automatically, but regardless I think your code will help me to improve my program.