# Trying to change image of moving character in every 0.25 seconds PyGame

Tags: python, time, pygame, pygame-clock, pygame-tick

So i am trying to 'animate' my character in pygame by changing between 2 pictures when he walks. I tried to use the code that was mentioned here: [In PyGame, how to move an image every 3 seconds without using the sleep function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109410/in-pygame-how-to-move-an-image-every-3-seconds-without-using-the-sleep-function) but it didn't turn out too well. In fact my character only uses one image when walking. here the part of the code and some variables:

- self.xchange: change on x axis
- self.img: image for when the character stands still
- self.walk1 and self.walk2: the two images i am trying to use to
  animate my character
- self.x and self.y are the cordinates
  screen is the surface

.

```
def draw(self):
        self.clock = time.time()
        if self.xchange != 0:
            if time.time() <= self.clock + 0.25:
                screen.blit(self.walk1, (self.x, self.y))
            elif time.time() > self.clock + 0.25:
                screen.blit(self.walk2, (self.x, self.y))
                if time.time() > self.clock + 0.50:
                    self.clock = time.time()
        else: 
            screen.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: The first line of the function resets the clock every time. Try removing that line.

Comment: thank you! i moved the line to the __init__ part of my class and it worked thanks!

Comment: You might find it easier/better to use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` rather than `time.time()`, because the former gives you an integer millisecond count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pygame the system time can be obtained by calling [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks), which returns the number of milliseconds since [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) was called. See [`pygame.time`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) module.

Use an attribute `self.walk_count` to animate the character. Add an attribute `animate_time` to the class that indicates when the animation image needs to be changed. Compare the current time with `animate_time` in `draw()`. If the current time exceeds `animate_time`, increment `self.walk_count` and calculate the next `animate_time`.

```py
class Player:

    def __init__(self):

        self.animate_time = None
        self.walk_count = 0
 
    def draw(self):

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        current_img = self.img
        
        if self.xchange != 0:
            current_img = self.walk1 if self.walk_count % 2 == 0 else self.walk2

            if self.animate_time == None:
                self.animate_time = current_time + 250 # 250 milliseconds == 0.25 seconds
            elif current_time >= self.animate_time
                self.animate_time += 250
                self.walk_count += 1
        else: 
            self.animate_time = None
            self.walk_count = 0

        screen.blit(current_img, (self.x, self.y))
```